# Why does std::exception have extra constructors in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, standards

Something I noticed just now. Definition of `exception` in [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) (18.6.1):

```
class exception {
public :
    exception() throw();
    exception(const exception &) throw();
    exception& operator=(const exception&) throw();
    virtual ~exception() throw();
    virtual const char* what() const throw();
};
```

Definition of `exception` in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4ts6d5a%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
class exception {
public:
   exception(); 
   exception(const char *const&);
   exception(const char *const&, int);
   exception(const exception&); 
   exception& operator=(const exception&); 
   virtual ~exception();
   virtual const char *what() const;
};
```

It would seem that Microsoft's version allows you to specify the error message for an `exception` object, while the standard version only lets you do that for the derived classes (but doesn't prevent you from creating a generic `exception` with an undefined message).

I know this is pretty insignificant, but still. Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: I would have guessed that the additional overloads were there because they were there in older, possibly pre-standard versions of the library, but it looks like they were actually added in Visual C++ 2005 (they aren't present in the Visual C++ 2003 documentation).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not really any good reason. The MS implementation has chosen to put the string handling in std::exception instead of in each class derived from it (<stdexcept>).

As they actually also provide the interface required by the standard, this can be seen as a conforming extension. Programs following the standard works as expected.

Other implementations do not do it this way, so portable programs should not use the extra constructors.

Comment: Those extra constructors aren't `explicit` though, at least not in the quote in the question. Isn't it an incompatible change to add an implicit conversion, since it could break someone's SFINAE code?

Comment: @Steve: They could be detected, but I also believe that an implementation is allowed to add extra constructors. For sure the standard (17.4.4.4) says that an implementation can add non-virtual member functions. It doesn't explicitly say that this includes **special** member functions, but doesn't exclude them either.   In this particular case I would have made them protected, as it is an implementation detail for the derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of the throw specification was a good idea. Although they shouldn't throw, throw specifications are generally bad.

Putting in extensions will make code non-portable but is likely to fix slicing issues where people "catch" a std::exception by value and it can copy the string in locally from what it is copying in.

I don't see the advantage in the int, nor of non-explicit constructors that take one parameter.

Comment: MSDN says: "The int parameter allows you to specify that no memory should be allocated. The value of the int is ignored." That's another round of confusing, you'd think they could have just used a `bool` parameter with a default value.

Comment: Visual C++ doesn't fully support exception specifications anyway.

Comment: @James:  Exception specifications seem to be generally considered a bad idea, and are going to be overhauled radically in the next C++ standard.

Comment: @David: Right. I meant that comment more as "the compiler with which this Standard Library implementation is used does not support exception specifications, which is probably the reason they are not present." I could be wrong though; there could be some other reason.